# Promise catch behavior

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

it seems the following works without throwing an error:

```
var p = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        reject('ko');
    }, 1000);
});

p.then(function (value) { console.log(value); })
.catch(function () { console.log('catched'); });
// → 'catched'
```

But this throws an error:

```
var p = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        p.catch(function () { console.log('catched'); });
        reject('ko');
    }, 1000);
});

p.then(function (value) { console.log(value); });
// → 'catched'
// Uncaught (in promise) ko
```

Any wild guesses to why ?

Comment: It's because you have not handled the error in your `p.then` chain ... each `p.then` or `p.catch` is independent and each must (eventually) handle errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.catch` must be directly chained after `.then`. Even if you write it this way, it will still report uncaught:

```js
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    //p.catch(function () { console.log('catched'); });
    console.log(p)
    reject('ko');
  }, 1000);
});

p.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
});
p.catch(function() {
  console.log('catched');
});
```

The reason for this is that if you don't chain it like that, the `.catch` function doesn't receive the return value that gets generated when you call `.then`

Comment: I see your point, but how would you implement an error catcher from inside the `setTimeout()` than ? Since native promises do not have any `done()` method. I'm not sure it is possible. This is of course considering the fact that i am giving someone a `Promise` and want to catch eventual errors they make with it.

Comment: If you want that functionality, your best bet is probably to have them pass a `next` function with the request for the promise. So, you'd wind up with `function createPromise(next){ var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){}); p.then(next).catch(function(){ console.log('Error Caught') })`

Comment: Yes but they than loose the possibility to chain methods.

Comment: I guess then it becomes a question of who "they" are, it sounds like they might need to do the error handling on their side.