# node: add catch-function to promise after construction

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Consider this code:

```js
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log("run");
    setTimeout(reject, 5);
});

p.catch(function() {
    console.log("cought!");
});

p.then(function() {
    console.log("then!");
});
```

Output (browser):

```
run
cought!
```

Here, in the browser it behaves like expected. Bun ran as a node-script I get:

```
run
cought!
(node:13927) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: undefined
(node:13927) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13927) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**So the rejection got catched, but node is still complaining - why that?**

I could chain everything together as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751143/promise-catch-behavior) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993027/where-should-i-catch-promise-errors-between-separate-functions):

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log("run");
    setTimeout(reject, 5);
}).then(function() {
    console.log("then!");
}).catch(function() {
    console.log("cought!");
});
```

Output (browser and node):

```
run
cought!
```

In my usecase I can't use this solution, because I have a factory-function which builds the Promise. The catch- and then-functions shall be attached by the factory's caller.In case of then-function it works, but not for catch. **How could I avoid this warning?**

Comment: Can you give more details about what you mean: "The catch- and then-functions shall be attached by the factory's caller." Why does this prevent you from chaining?

Comment: Yeah, please add the code that is calling the this code.

Comment: try async await here it might help

Comment: Your promise code is never resolving and hence it will never reach `then` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promises are multicast, so each time you call `.then` or `.catch` you get a new promise object (chain) back. That is, `p.then` and `p.catch` both return their own separate promise objects. This means that there is no catch path for `p.then`.

If chaining the promises together is not possible, then you'll have to handle the error in the new promise chain created by `.then`. You can swallow this exception if you so choose, but it *is* a separate exception:

```
p.then(function() {
    console.log("then!");
}).catch(() => {});
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Async Await to solve this problem hope it helps, works fine in my computer.

```
const iReturnPromise = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("run");
        setTimeout(reject, 5);
    });
}

async function displayPromiseResults() {

    try {
        await iReturnPromise();
        console.log('!then');
    }

    catch(ex) {
        console.log("cought!");
    }

}

displayPromiseResults();
```